# ¿Donde debo validar los datos ingresados por un usuario cuando trabajo en 3 capas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, mvc

Cordial saludo.
Estoy trabando en un  programa con el modelo 3 capas (Vista, modelo y Controlador) pero me surge la duda de en que capa debo validar la información ingresada por un usuario con esto quiero decir verificar que un campo no este vació, que no ingrese caracteres alfabéticos en un campo que solo espera números por ejemplo un numero de teléfono.

Comment: mi única referencia es el Framework Laravel que aunque es n capas; hace dichas validaciones en el controlador

Comment: ¿Has intentado/investigado algo?

Comment: yo por lo general valido en el controlador que es el que primero recibe los datos y controla para donde salir, luego en el modelo haces mas checks para sanitizar

Comment: En mi experiencia personal, las validaciones de caracteres tipos de datos y hasta cierto punto lógicos y algunas reglas de negocio los debes hacer en la vista, los lógicos y/o reglas de negocio de preferencia en el controlador y en el modelo puedes controlar cosas como longitudes, tipos de datos y campos obligatorios, aunque estos también los puedes hacer en la vista, es cuestión como de comodidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo utilizo MVVM porque sinceramente pienso que MVC es demasiado antiguo para interfaces gráficas modernas, está bien para cosas mas estáticas como la web.

Te voy a explicar como hago la validación en mis proyectos.

La clase base que utilizo  para mis ViewModels implementa la interfaz IDataErrorInfo y utilizo las dataannotations para validar, aquí un ejemplo de un ViewModel en mi framework MVVM:

```
public class PersonaViewModel : ViewModel
{
    readonly DateTime MinDate = new DateTime(1940, 01,01);
    readonly DateTime MaxDate = DateTime.Today;

    // constructor
    public PersonaViewModel()
    {
        // la propiedad "Edad" se recalcula automáticamente cada que la propiedad FechaNacimiento cambia de valor, es como en excel cuando le pones fórmula a una celda
        this.Edad = this.CreateFormula(
            property: This => This.FechaNacimiento,
            formula: value => DateTime.Today.AddTicks(-value.Ticks).Year - 1);

        // puedeGuardar es una variable que cambia automáticamente cuando el viewmodel cambia su estado de validación
        // ValidationState es una propiedad de la clase ViewModel que contiene el estado de validación del ViewModel que estás creando,
        //  y cambia cada vez que alguna propiedad del viewmodel es modificada
        //  y tiene una propiedad "HasErrors" que es true si alguna propiedad del ViewModel no pasa la validación
        var puedeGuardar = this.ValidationState
            .When(state => state.HasErrors == false); // puede ser !state.HasErrors pero lo pongo así por claridad

        // al comando le paso "puedeGuardar" para indicar cuándo va a estar "enabled" el botón donde lo voy a bindear en la vista
        this.GuardarDatos = new AsyncCommand(
            method = this.Guardar,
            isEnabled = puedeGuardar);
    }

    // este comando guarda los datos capturados
    public Command GuardarDatos { get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre no puede estar vacío")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El nombre no puede tener mas de 50 caracteres")]
    public string Nombre
    {
         get => Get<string>();
         set => Set(value);
    }

   [ValidateMethod] // utiliza un método "IsXXXXXValid" para validad donde XXXXX es un nombre de propiedad
   public DateTime FechaNacimiento
   {
       get => Get<DateTime>();
       set => Set(value);
   }

   // esta propiedad se calcula automáticamente cada que la fecha de nacimiento cambia, es inicializada en el constructor
   public Calculated<int> Edad { get;}

   // este método valida la propiedad fechanacimiento
   private bool IsFechaNacimientoValid(DateTime date)
   {
       return date >= MinDate && date <= MaxDate;
   }

    // en este método guardo los datos
   private async Task Guardar()
   {
       // aquí guardo los datos a la base de datos
   }
}
```

Como ves, la clase hereda de ViewModel, que implementa validación en sus propiedades, en el formulario únicamente agrego un control tipo ErrotProvider (ya viene de serie), y solo hago un override de un método donde "bindeo" cada propiedad del ViewModel con cada control en el formulario:

```
// formulario, hereda de una clase Form preparada con funcionalidad para bindeo
public class PersonaView : FormBase, IView<PersonaViewModel>
{

    public PersonaViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    // dentro de la clase de mi formulario sobrecargo el método OnBinding
    private override void OnBinding(Binder binder)
    {
         binder.Add(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.Nombre, This => This.nombreTextBox.Text);

         binder.Add(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.FechaNacimiento, This => This.fechaDateTimePicker.Value);

         binder.AddReadOnly(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.Edad.Value, This => This.EdadLabel.Text);

         binder.AddCommand(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.GuardarDatos, This => This.btnGuardar);
    }
}
```

Y listo, como ves, es sencillo, la validación la hago tanto a nivel IU, en la captura cada control pone un aviso de error en color rojo y el mensaje de error de validación y el botón btnGuardar se pone disable si alguna propiedad no pasa su validación, como a nivel ViewModel, por ejemplo el comando GuardarDatos del ViewModel no se ejecuta si alguna propiedad del ViewModel no pasa la validación.

Así que en cuanto a tu pregunta, yo diría que si vas a validar puedes hacerlo en la vista, pero pienso que es repetir código pudiendo implementar algo que puedas reutilizar.

Haces bien en utilizar un patrón de diseño, en tu caso MVC,  en mi caso uso MVVM porque no solo permite separar la lógica de tu aplicación o poder reutilizar tus ViewModels en otras plataformas (por ejemplo una app Xamarin), sino también no repetir código, no repetir la implementación de validaciones para cada modelo.

Answer (score 2):

La manera más fácil de validar lo que tu mencionas, es que lo valides desde la vista, expresiones regulares, mascaras, métodos que verifiquen los datos, de esta forma si ha sucedido algún problema con los datos ingresados por el usuario, lo puede saber rápidamente, sin necesidad de hacer conexión al servidor.

Pero a la vez también es muy recomendable aplicar una segunda fase de seguridad por así decirlo, que normalmente es el controlador, antes de enviar los datos al modelo para que interactuen con la base de datos, el controlador los vuelve a validar dejando fuera cualquier problema causado por los datos que ingresa el usuario.

si haces lo segundo, te recomiendo tener una clase con los métodos que necesitaras normalmente, de esta forma esa clase seria tu validador y solo tendras que llamarla, mas que todo para no repetir código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me haz ayudado mucho.

Comment: De nada, recuerda puntuar a las preguntas que te hayan aportado algo, o marcar como correctas si resuelven tu problematica